# How can I specify the last parameters in a function call and let the others default to the DEFAULT in the declaration?

Tags: postgresql, functions

I have a function with 5 parameters,

- arguments `p1`, and `p2` are mandatory
- arguments `p3`, `p4`, and `p5` are optional and have a `DEFAULT` set

The function looks like this,

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_func(
  p1 int,
  p2 int,
  p3 int DEFAULT 3,
  p4 int DEFAULT 4,
  p5 int DEFAULT 5
)
  RETURNS int AS
$$
  SELECT p5;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

I can invoke it like this,

```
SELECT test_func(1,2,3,4,5);
 test_func 
-----------
         5
```

But I would like to allow p3 and p4 to default and invoke it like this,

```
SELECT test_func(1,2,5);
```

Is there a way to specify the value for the last optional parameter (`p5`) without giving values to the preceding ones (`p3`, `p4`)? I don't want to hard-code default values for the `p3`, `p4` in the call for `test_func`, because I may need to change their default values in the future.

Comment: This related answer on SO addresses it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16789179/939860 Almost exactly 6 years old (with updates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply supply the fifth argument with [Mixed Notation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CALLING-FUNCS-MIXED) using the `=>` to separate the parameter name from the argument,

```
SELECT test_func(1,2,3,p5=>5);
test_func 
-----------
         5
(1 row)
```

From the docs on [*mixed notation*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CALLING-FUNCS-MIXED) with the one caveat (from the docs),

> Named and mixed call notations currently cannot be used when calling an aggregate function (but they do work when an aggregate function is used as a window function).